90's TV show like Power Rangers
I'm looking for a 90's show with 3 heroes (red, black, yellow or violet).
Each have different powers:

Red have eagle power and eagle like ride
Black have a black jaguar like ride
Yellow or violet I don't remember

They have power to combine all their rides into one form.
Transformation from human to hero is by taping the top of a remote or something like that (similar to spd emergency power rangers).

sounds a bit like voltron where there are 5 lions of different colours and abilities, and they all join together to form Voltron

Big Bad Beetleborgs/Beetleborgs Metallix (1996-1998)
It was a popular American TV series in which 3 kids are granted their wish i.e. to become their favorite comic book superheroes: The Beetleborgs. It was the most successful spin-off of Power Rangers and was created by Saban Entertainment (creators of Power Rangers).


Justirisers
The Justirisers are three chosen humans who are granted the use of the mysterious Justipower, the "Earth's will" that was discovered by the Riserseijin Noulan who utilized it to seal away Kaiser Hades long ago. Each of those powers are based on the Four Symbols of Chinese Origin. Each one is equipped with an In-Loader that allows them to summon a high-powered suit of armor that transforms them into a Justiriser. The transformation call is "Souchaku!" ("Equip!"). The In-Loader also acts as a communications device between the three Justirisers.

It's Chouseshin Gransazer. From Wikipedia:

The premise of this series is similar to both the Super Sentai series and the manga/anime series Saint Seiya: there are 12 heroes, divided into four tribes, and each tribe has a giant transforming robot.

